# QRadioButton style

Tags: qt, qradiobutton

Is it possible to make a QRadioButton which  looks  like a button,and changes it's background when checked? Which property of the class i should refer to?

How to create a menu similar to this one:

[image: menu]

Any examples? I'm using QT 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QRadioButton` is a `QAbstractButton`. you can use stylesheet to style it. you can use any of these pseudo states `:checked` `:disabled` `:enabled` `:focus` `:hover` `:indeterminate` `:pressed` `:unchecked`

You can also make your own style by inheriting [`QStyle`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstyle.html) and latter feed that style to your application.

You can inherit `QAbstractButton` and check [`QAbstractButton::setCheckable`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop)

Check Out this [`QML` Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-mobile-guitartuner-src-mycomponents-togglebutton-qml.html)

Comment: Thanks! The stylesheets are probably what i need. I will read about them

Comment: One more newbie question: Suppose i want to draw  a picture on the button. How can i make the picture a part of the project?Is there any possibility to create some inner project resource so it will be included to binary automatically and i will not need to deliver it separately from  the executable file?

Comment: You don't need to draw. You can `setIcon()` for a Button. that icon will be part of the resource (qrc). and the resource will be part of your executable

Comment: Great, thank you for the help.. Icons are probably what i need. Sorry for the stupid questions,and i'm very noob in designing GUIs and it takes so much time to find necessary things in the documentation...